# C/C++: do built-in objects such as `int` `double` always stay in the exact place within memory in the duration of the program?

Tags: c++, memory, types, built-in

Do built-in types which are **not** defined dynamically, always stay in the same piece of memory during the duration of the program?

If it's something I should understand how do I go about and check it?

i.e.

```
int j = 0;
double k = 2.2;
double* p = &k;
```

Does the system architecture or compiler move around all these objects if a C/C++ program is, say, highly memory intensive?

Note: I'm not talking about containers such as `std::vectors<T>`. These can obviously reallocate in certain situations, but again this is dynamic.

---

<strike>**side question:**
The following scenario will obviously raise a few eyebrows. Just as an example, will this pointer always be valid during the duration of the program?</strike>

*This side-question is obsolete, thanks to my ignorance!*

```
struct null_deleter
{
    void operator() (void const *) const {};
};

int main()
{
    // define object
    double b=0;

    // define shared pointer
    std::shared_ptr<double> ptr_store;
    ptr_store.reset(&b,null_deleter()); // this works and behaves how you would expect
}
```

Comment: Yes they're guaranteed to stay in place. I wish I had some reference to prove it. It's something so basic most people just take it for granted.

Comment: If you never modify `p` after that statement, then `p == &k` will always be true.  Is that what you're curious about?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your side question.  For the lifetime of `b`, `&b` will always evaluate to the same value in a well-defined manner...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You are dead right. I was just so concerned with `b` relocating around in memory. Apologies my ignorance! Just reading through all the answers below also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the abstract machine, an object's address does not change during that object's lifetime.

(The word "object" here does not refer to "object-oriented" anything; an "object" is merely a region of storage.)

That really means that a program must behave *as if* an object's address never changes. A compiler can generate code that plays whatever games it likes, including moving objects around or not storing them anywhere at all, as long as such games don't affect the visible behavior in a way that violates the standard.

For example, this:

```
int n;
int *addr1 = &n;
int *addr2 = &n;
if (addr1 == addr2) {
    std::cout << "Equal\n";
}
```

must print "Equal" -- but a clever optimizing compiler could legally eliminate everything but the output statement.

The ISO C standard states this explcitly, in section 6.2.4:

> The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout
>   its lifetime.

with a (non-normative) footnote:

> The term "constant address" means that two pointers to the object
>   constructed at possibly different times will compare equal. The
>   address may be different during two different executions of the same
>   program.

I haven't found a similar explicit statement in the C++ standard; either I'm missing it, or the authors considered it too obvious to bother stating.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to do whatever it wants, so long as it doesn't affect the observable program behaviour.

Firstly, consider that local variables might not even get put in memory (they might get stored in registers only, or optimized away entirely).

So even in your example where you take the address of a local variable, that doesn't mean that it **has** to live in a fixed location in memory.  It depends what you go on to do with it, and whether the compiler is smart enough to optimize it.  For example, this:

```
double k = 2.2;
double *p = &k;
*p = 3.3;
```

is probably equivalent to this:

```
double k = 3.3;
```

Comment: The pedant in me wants to say that it's actually probably equivalent to no code at all, in the absence of further context!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Global variables will stay in the same place.

Stack variables (inside a function) will get allocated and deallocated each time the function is called and returns.  For example:

```
void k(int);
void f() {
    int x;
    k(x);
}
void g() {
    f();
}
int main() {
    f();
    g();
}
```

Here, the second time `f()` is called, it's `x` will be in a different location.

Comment: The second time `f()` is called, you have a different object named `x`. The original one still exists, and still has its original address.

Comment: @Hal: Not necessarily.  `x` might not be in memory at all.

Comment: I was also surprised by the other answer. Every stack-allocated variable **can** move around, depending on the current stack pointer (esp, on the x86). If a function is called at different depths in the call stack, every local (`auto`) variable within the function **will** be at a different location.

Comment: @RahulBanerjee: Depends on the definition of a "variable" here.  "Objects" never move during their lifetime, but a local name can refer to different objects, once per function invocation.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Agreed. We're splitting hairs here. I think OP's question is a little too broad for such semantic discussions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to this question, depending on factors you haven't mentioned.

- If a data object's address is never taken, then a conforming C program cannot tell whether or not it even *has* an address.  It might exist only in registers, or be optimized completely out; if it does exist in memory, it need not have a fixed address.
- Data objects with "automatic" *storage duration* (to first approximation, function-local variables not declared with `static`) are created each time their containing function is invoked and destroyed when it exits; there may be multiple copies of them at any given time, and there's no guarantee that a new instance of one has the same address as an old one.
- We speak of the `&` operator as "taking the address" of a data object, but technically speaking that's not what it does.  It constructs a *pointer* to that data object.  Pointers are opaque entities in the C standard.  If you inspect the bits (by converting to integer) the result is implementation-defined.  And if you inspect the bits twice in a row there is no guarantee that you get the same number!  A hypothetical garbage-collected C implementation *could* track all pointers to each datum and update them as necessary when it moved the heap around.  (People have actually tried this.  It tends to break programs that don't stick to the letter of the rules.)

Comment: According to the (C) standard `&` really does "yield the **address** of its operand".  The result is of pointer type.